# Graph API: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following permissions on my registered application:

[image]

but when I try to get data

```
        var currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

I receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ServiceException: Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

what is wrong in my case?

Comment: Permissions are enough, you used `Me` here so you used delegated permission. May I know how you created `_graphServiceClient`? Or do you get an `access token`? If you got the access token, you may try to decode the token and check if it has correct `scp` claim. If you don't know how to get the token, I'm afraid you need to show us how you set `_graphServiceClient`.. By the way, are you sure the application you showed in your screenshot is the one you used to generate `_graphServiceClient`?

Comment: Hi Oleg SH, can you please share your query request id, client id and timestamp so that we can check the logs from backend.